# Small issue over DDMS data folder

Tags: android

I am new to android . So i was trying to implement a code which stores the data in the internal storage of the device. It is storing and loading the data. I cannot see the file in the data folder  which is present in the eclipse. When i click the data folder , it is not expanding.
[image: The data folder is clicked but could not see any files inside it]

I have used the below code

```
package com.example.files;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText textBox;
    static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText1);
    }
    public void onClickSave(View view){
        String str = textBox.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fOut =
                    openFileOutput("textfile.txt",
                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new
                    OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            //---write the string to the file---
            osw.write(str);
            osw.flush(); 
            osw.close();
            //---display file saved message---
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "File saved successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //---clears the EditText---
            textBox.setText("");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onClickLoad(View view) {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fIn = 
                    openFileInput("textfile.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new 
                    InputStreamReader(fIn);
            char[] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            String s = "";
            int charRead;
            while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
            {
                //---convert the chars to a String---
                String readString =
                        String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0,
                                charRead);
                s += readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            }
            //---set the EditText to the text that has been 
            // read---
            textBox.setText(s);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "File loaded successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have u run app first time? When u run app at that time you can see that..

Comment: ya i know .See the left side the device is displayed .It is not expanded .So the app is present inside the device folder.

Comment: see under `/data/data/your_package_name`...

Comment: Post the code. The screen shot just shows the symptom. We can only guess at the cause.

Comment: @weston I have posted the code and

Comment: @GopalRao See the first data folder is not expanding to show subfolder.So i cannot access others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data folder is part of the internal storage of the device and should not be accessible over DDMS for a device.

You can however run your app on the emulator and then you can browse the emulator's data directory in DDMS.

The apps in all new smartphone OS's work on the concept of sandboxing. In case of Android the sandbox directory for an app is /data/data/your_app_package/

The files and directories in this directory are by default only available to the app. If you want to view the files using DDMS on a device, I suggest you get a handle on the External Storage using getExternalStorage() and copy/move your files there. The default location to save your files in the app is getFilesDir() which /data/data/your_app_package/files

Comment: Ok i understand that. Now will the file be created in the local storage some where .So that i can stop app and then see the file in the file explorer.

Comment: Ok i am storing in the external storage can i view in the DDMS

Comment: ,If i am storing in internal storage and i am trying to find the file in my mobile phone will i see it?

Comment: I got some regarding this what was told is that if the device is not rooted devices then the data/data/package_name cannot be seen and if that is true , how to root the devices to the eclipse or my machine

Comment: Rooting means you are jail breaking your device. And it is not a suggested way of doing things.

Comment: I know that ,but i heared that the devices that are not rooted usually dont allow us to see data/data/ folder . So what should i do.

Comment: In mobile phone also i cannot see the file with the name testfile.text which stored using the above code. And how i say it is stored is that when i am loading that i could see the text in the file

Comment: No read my question , understand all my comments. I saved a file with a name textfile in phone's internal storage.text with the content something from text box using a openfileOutput function. When i load it ,it is also displaying the content . But i couldnt find the textfile.text outside the application.

Answer (score 0):

The constant MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated.

If you want to write a file that can be seen externally, then use [Environment.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

Note it doesn't mean the file will be on external storage.