# How I'll get database from DDMS

Tags: android

I had created database to my Android App, to see that I can search it through DDMS file explorer and go through data/data directory also. But there is no my project/package name present.

Please help me make it possible soon.

Comment: You have to first select the device in the left pane.

Comment: Here every question we look at same priority

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the same question . And answer came for me .I am referring to that question .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951402/small-issue-over-ddms-data-folder

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @codeMagic but this has the answer and answer can be given in the answer column

Comment: The **link** has the answer which is why it was marked as a dupe. If you are going to **just** provide a link then it should be a comment and, in this case, be marked as a dupe.